# How can I get IMG to match height of row in 2 column responsive layout?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 2 column responsive layout as you can see in [this example](http://www.blazenweb.com/2-column-responsive-image-and-text-block/)

If you start with a full width desktop browser and keep reducing the width of the browser (eg viewport width 870px), you will see that the layout starts to look strange because the photo is no longer the height of the row/parent container/text block.

Does anyone know of a solution where I could get the photo to have the same height as the row? I assume they'd need to be a certain amount of cropping of the photo's left and right to make sure it fits.

The effect I'm looking for is the same kind of thing as background:cover, but I want to use an actual image in the content of the page.

I can't change the structure of the HTML layout, but could add CSS and some javascript.

The solution needs to be one that is 'programmed' into the website, so that non technical people can easily insert photos that have this effect. Also the solution needs to be scalable, i.e if I was doing this 100 times on a website, I just want to upload the one photo.

Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: How about just adding three different ratio photos, and using media query to decide which one should display?

Comment: Thanks Ian, I've now cleared that up in the question. The solution needs to be one that is 'programmed' into the website, so that non technical people can easily insert photos that have this effect. Also the solution needs to be scalable, i.e if I was doing this 100 times on a website, I just want to upload the one photo, rather than 300.

Comment: What's wrong with percentage height?

Comment: A percentage height will give me a distorted image?